Python. Telebot. Too Many Requests
Всем привет.
Есть бот, написанный на telebot, python. При частом нажатии на кнопки выдаётся ошибка "Too Many Requests: retry after 32". Искал информацию в сети и нашёл, что можно поиграться параметром timeout или interval в bot.polling(), но конкретного объяснения не встретил. Так же встречал рекомендации использовать infinity_polling. Может кто-то в двух словах объяснить как постараться избежать ошибки?

Ошибка прилетает от telegram bot api, означает что слишком много запросов приходит от бота. Используя лонгпуллинг, вы всегда будете с ней сталкиваться. Рекомендую использовать вебхуки, c ними меньше ограничений. https://habr.com/ru/companies/otus/articles/786754/
Почитайте про различия в статье.

Для меня это пока что сложно.
